# Append String values until reaches at least 10 character long

Tags: java

The method inspect the fields of the o object. If the fields value less than 10 character long it has to append the same value until it reaches at leat 10 character long. 
But with this code the output is only the following: writes to the console 10 times every value of the fields doubling the value.

So If I have a field e.g. `String name = "John";`
it writes: "JohnJohn" x10, but I want to write it "JohnJohnJohn" 1 time.

```
public void correctAtLeastTenCharsMegsértések(Object o) {

    Class<?> objClass = o.getClass();
    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {

        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(o);
        if (value instanceof String)
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                if (((String) value).length() < 10) {
                    field.set(o, (String) value + value);
                    System.out.println((String) value + (String) value);
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
public void correctAtLeastTenCharsMegsértések(Object o)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class<?> objClass = o.getClass();
    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {

        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(o);
        if (value instanceof String) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((String)value);
            while (sb.length() > 0 && sb.length() < 10) {
                sb.append(value);
            }
            field.set(o, sb.toString());
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

First we get the `value` of the field. If it's of type `String`, then we create a local variable `adaptedValue` to store the end result (the one that will contain a minimum of 10 characters). It is initially set to the value of the field. We then append the value to this `adaptedValue` as long as it is less than 10 characters.

Comment: Edit your post and include your explanation. That way it's more helpful.

Comment: Two things; 1- You should avoid string concatenation within loops; 2- A String; 2- `&` isn't going to work, its a bitwise operator, not a boolean operator

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I fixed the & typo. Also replaced string concatenation with using a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to update the value of object value.
value still contains the old data.

```
Object value = field.get(o);
                   if(value instanceof String)
                       for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
                       if (((String)value).length() < 10){
                             field.set(o, (String)value + value);
                           System.out.println((String) value + (String) value);
value = field.get(o);
                       }
```

Comment: Yes but the if condition is check on value, which still holds the old reference.
It needs to have the new reference and it works fine, I checked it @azurefrog

Comment: @JimGarrison: It would go into an infinite loop.
You can check it the way I have written please upvote it as it works.

Comment: yes, the while loop is an infinite loop here, i tried also

Comment: @REPARATUR: Can you please check the approach I mentioned and mark it as suitable if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by processing the value separately from the display, once you've achieved the result you want, display...

```
String value = ...;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
while (sb.length() < 10) {
    sb.append(value);
}
value = sb.toString();
field.set(o, value);
System.out.println(value);
```

Instead of using `String` concatenation (string + string) in loops, which is highly inefficient, you should get use to using a `StringBuilder`

If the value must be exactly 10 characters long you could add, after the `while-loop`

```
if (sb.length() > 10) {
    sb.delete(10, sb.length());
}
```

Which will trim the result to be exactly 10 characters long

While not stated, you might also want to add a check for a `0` length `String`, just in case...